# Applying macro on existing data

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel sheet (exactly multiple sheets which looks the same) where I want to apply macro to change existing data. If value in cells is above 4.0 I need to change it, also I want to add "-" symbol if a cell is empty.
I know my formula will look something like this:

```
if(x>=4,RANDBETWEEN(28,39)/10,x)
```

It would be nice if a macro had shortcut like: ctrl+a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select the cells and try this:

```
Sub laszlo()
    Dim r As Range, v As Variant

    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Value
        If v = "" Then
            r.Value = "-"
        ElseIf IsNumeric(v) Then
            If v >= 4 Then
                r.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.RandBetween(28, 39) / 10
            End If
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```